# Какие темы по C# достаточно знать для junior-a и для понимания и изучения технологии asp.net?

Tags: c#

Сейчас я читаю главу в Шилдте про linq в C#, пытаюсь также написать свой небольшой проект (сжатие данных с помощью алгоритма Хаффмана). Параллельно я учу html/css. В дальнейшем я хочу специализироваться в asp.net. Знаю, что мне понадобиться изучать еще mssql. Меня интересует, каких тем для знаний junior-а, чтобы было достаточно понимания и знания языка для изучения asp.net и возможности устраиваться на работу? Я не думаю, что новичку нужно знать все моменты C#.

Answer (score 2):

Просто прочитайте книгу [Microsoft ASP.NET 4 с примерами на C# 2010 для профессионалов](http://www.ozon.ru/context/detail/id/6279214/)

Несмотря на то, что написано в названии "для профессионалов" книга больше подходит для изучающих ASP.NET с нуля.

Answer (score 1):

для juniora необходимо знать, как создавать юзер контролы, хранимые процедуры MS SQL, основы ajax - отправку/получение данных без постбэков, основные алгоритмы и структуры данных. Собственно это всё.